# Python expand nested json

Tags: python, json, nested

I need to expand the json below:

```
data = [
   'elements': {
      "totalPageStatistics":{
         "clicks":{
            "mobileCustomButtonClickCounts":[
               {
                  "customButtonType":"VIEW_WEBSITE",
                  "clicks":0
               }
            ],
            "careersPageClicks":{
               "careersPagePromoLinksClicks":0,
               "careersPageBannerPromoClicks":0,
               "careersPageJobsClicks":0,
               "careersPageEmployeesClicks":0
            },
            "desktopCustomButtonClickCounts":[
               {
                  "customButtonType":"VIEW_WEBSITE",
                  "clicks":0
               }
            ],
            "mobileCareersPageClicks":{
               "careersPageJobsClicks":0,
               "careersPagePromoLinksClicks":0,
               "careersPageEmployeesClicks":0
            }
         },
         "views":{
            "mobileProductsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "allDesktopPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "insightsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "mobileAboutPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "allMobilePageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopProductsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "productsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "jobsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "peoplePageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "overviewPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "mobileOverviewPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "lifeAtPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopOverviewPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "mobileCareersPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "allPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "mobileJobsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "careersPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "mobileLifeAtPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopJobsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopPeoplePageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "aboutPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopAboutPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "mobilePeoplePageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopInsightsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopCareersPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "desktopLifeAtPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            },
            "mobileInsightsPageViews":{
               "pageViews":0,
               "uniquePageViews":0
            }
         }
      },
      "timeRange":{
         "start":1640995200000,
         "end":1641081600000
      },
      "organization":"urn:li:organization:111111111"
   }
]
```

Here's my code:

(1) Option:

```
flat_data = json_normalize(data['elements'])
flat_data.rename(dict((x, x.split('.')[-1]) for x in flat_data.columns if '.' in x), axis=1, inplace=True)
flat_data
```

(2) Using flatten_json

```
flat = flatten_json(data)
flat_data = json_normalize(flat)
```

Option (1) worked better:

[image]

However, I don't know to expand the columns (screenshot in red). Please, is there anyone that could explain to me how to do that?
Thanks

**EDIT**:
Below is an example of what the table should look like.
[image]

Using the flatten_json library I am getting this (one unique row), and I find hark to work this way.
[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there how the output should look like (small example)?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks for the answer. I've edited my question to show the output.

Comment: I am also open for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my issue:

1. explode the 2 columns
2. concatenate with the main df
3. drop the original columns

```
flat_data = json_normalize(data['elements'])
dd = flat_data.explode(['totalPageStatistics.clicks.mobileCustomButtonClickCounts', 'totalPageStatistics.clicks.desktopCustomButtonClickCounts']).reset_index()
ff = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dd), 
                json_normalize(dd['totalPageStatistics.clicks.mobileCustomButtonClickCounts']),
                json_normalize(dd['totalPageStatistics.clicks.desktopCustomButtonClickCounts']),
                   ], 
                axis=1).drop(columns=['totalPageStatistics.clicks.mobileCustomButtonClickCounts', 'totalPageStatistics.clicks.desktopCustomButtonClickCounts'])
ff
```

It was not an ideal solution but at least I have some formatting to work on the data.